# How can I get pidgin to replace animations/graphics with their alt text?

Tags: pidgin

I have a few contacts who use annoying text-to-animation plugins in their clients, that do things like turn the word "hi" into an animation of Kermit the Frog waving at me, or other equally annoying non-sense.  This is even more annoying when it does the conversion mid-word, like turning "This" into "T<Kermit waving>s".

To get around this annoying behavior, I often find myself copying their text from pidgin, and pasting into a text editor, which always replaces the animations with their original text (presumably by way of some html ALT tag, or the moral equivalent).

Obviously pidgin knows what the original text was, because it was able to provide that text to the copy buffer.  So how can I get Pidgin to just show me the original text, as if there were no annoying animations in the first place?

Comment: Is there are a regex plugin available for Pidgin? I imagine it would be pretty straightforward to replace the tags with the alt text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is impossible to disable all the "smiles" with alt text yet. [Ticket](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/7523) has been opened quite some time ago for that problem.

However, it is possible to disable custom smiles

`Accounts` -> `Account Name` -> `Edit Account`->`Advanced`->`Show Custom Smileys`

Comment: What version of Pidgin is this in? I don't seem to have this option. On version Pidgin 2.10.8 (libpurple 2.10.8)

Comment: This answer is outdated, the menu paths don't exist anymore.  I've posted a more up-to-date answer for all you googlers out there.

Answer (score 1):

To disable custom smileys from your coworkers, you'll want to uncheck `Show Custom Smileys`:

`Accounts` -> `you@host` -> `Edit Account` -> `Advanced` -> `Show Custom Smileys`

To disable *all* smileys, even the defaults, you'll want to change your `Smiley Theme` to `none`:

`Tools` -> `Preferences` -> `Themes` -> `Smiley Theme`

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to disable formatting on incoming messages:

*Preferences* → *Conversations* → *Show formatting on incoming messages*

Comment: What is this option? Where can you find it? If you don't tell us how to configure the option, then your answer is essentially useless.

Comment: All that option does is get rid of typeface formatting, and replace the annoying animations with a "broken image" placeholder image.  Which is less annoying than animations, but also less useful, because then all the images look identical.